# Changing "prefixes" in the Harvard bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, babel, harvard-style

I am using the `harvard`-package for the bibliography of my reports, who are written i Norwegian. In my preamble i have the `babel`-package.

However, when I use i.e. the `@inbook` entry in my `.bib`-file, and specify a chapter, like this:

```
@INBOOK{LL94,
TITLE       = {Title of the chapter},
PUBLISHER   = {Publisher},
YEAR        = {2009},
MONTH       = {September},
CHAPTER     = {E},
SERIES      = {Title of the book},
}
```

it is printed like this in the bibliography:

> Title of the chapter (2009). Title of the book, Publisher, chapter E.

I want it to say *kapittel* instead of *chapter*. How do I do this?

And also, if I use the `@techreport` entry, and don't specify any `TYPE`, it's displayed as *Technical report*. Would it also be able to translate this into the Norwegian *Teknisk rapport*?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but would you consider switching to `biblatex`?  See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib for some info about the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "chapter" keyword is hardwired in the bibliography style file. If you want to change it, assuming you're using

```
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

then make a copy of `agsm.bst` that you find on your system and call it, say, `xagsm.bst`, keeping it next to your main document. Edit the copy finding where it has the string

```
"chapter"
```

(quotes included) and change it to

```
"\harvardchaptername "
```

(quotes and space included). Then in your main file preamble put

```
\providecommand{\harvardchaptername}{kapittel}
```

and modify the `\bibliographystyle` line into

```
\bibliographystyle{xagsm}
```

Some other modifications along the same lines might be necessary for other hardwired keywords.

In order to change the name of a TechReport it's sufficient to add the field

```
TYPE = {Teknisk rapport},
```

in the corresponding entry in the `.bib` file.